# What is the right way to use a QStateMachine for a text adventure game?

Tags: c++, database, qt4

I have seen a couple topics about this already but they were a bit vague for me so I decided to make this. I'm working on a little adventure game just for fun in Qt, its basically just text on the screen and the player inputs commands into a line edit widget which I then process and do the related action/event. Thing is, I am a little confused on how to approach this. I don't want to dig myself a hole by manually coding in lots of commands and events per room because it seems to just be a pain later on. So then I thought about using some sort of database to store the information but which one should I use? I would love some advice from people who have tried something similar.

And here, these pictures are a rough outline of what I am trying to do.

**Flowchart of states**

[image: Flowchart of states]

**Level tiles**

[image: Level tiles]

Edit: I should add, the tiles for the level basically work like this. The light gray is a direction the player can move in, the dark gray parts are walls and the colors are various different actions you can do.

I don't particularly care for code, but I would like suggestions on what tools to use for this and maybe how to set them up right. Someone must know.

Comment: Try to ask your question on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I used xml and wrote a primitive editor, changes in levels would load a new xml file. Not sure if this is best, so leaving it as a comment.